# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have to show that those two field extensions are the same, however I'm struggling to get the job done.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})$

Comment: Do you know that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2 , e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}})$ is the smallest field containing $\Bbb Q, \sqrt[3] 2$ and $e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}}$?

Comment: $K(a,b)=K(a,ab)$ always.

Comment: Show that each of them is a subset of the other.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't just say that since $\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ is a product of elements from the set on the left the right set is in the left one, or can I ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sqrt[3] 2 , e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}} \in \Bbb Q (\sqrt[3] 2 , e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}})$, so $\sqrt[3] 2 e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2 , e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}})$. So $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2 , \sqrt[3] 2e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}}) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2 , e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}})$ because $\Bbb Q (\sqrt[3] 2 , \sqrt[3] 2 e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}})$ is the smallest field containing $\Bbb Q,  \sqrt[3] 2$ and  $\sqrt[3] 2 e^{\frac {2 \pi i} {3}}$. Can you show the other inclusion?

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. It's a field, so it's closed under multiplication aswell (Concerning your inclusion).

Comment: Yeah! @Christian Singer. Precisely it is!

Comment: Could you say that since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})$ is closed under multiplication, that it has to contain the inverse of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, hence the product $(\sqrt[3]{2})^{-1}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. If my train of thought is correct, this should have shown the other inclusion

Comment: Yes of course. That is precisely what I was trying to say.

Comment: Well, I edited at the same time that you posted your comment, so am I right that this basically shows the other inclusion ?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :-)!

Comment: You are most welcome @Christian Singer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89191/discussion-between-dbchatto67-and-christian-singer).